# How to raise NoSuchElementException inside another NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I have a whatsapp bot and I need to check for multiple elements in selenium one after the other like:

```
try:
  ....
except NoSuchElementException:
  ...
  try:
    ...
  except NoSuchElementException
```

I know that this isn't possible as it would raise `During handling the above exception, another exception occured`... and that stuff, I tried to use if as work around, but didn't work. Does anyone have any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your goal: to raise exception inside another exception or to check multiple elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This back to back `try-catch{}` block:

```
try:
  ....
except NoSuchElementException:
  ...
  try:
    ...
  except NoSuchElementException
```

have an indentation issue.

---

### Solution

You can check for multiple elements through multiple `try-catch{}` bolck as follows:

```
try:
  ....
  try:
    ...
  except NoSuchElementException:
    ...
except NoSuchElementException:
  ...
```